# How do I pivot my wide data set into a repeated instance long form if it's comprised of numeric and character-type data?

Tags: r

I am very new to R, but I'd like to format this wide data set I'm using into a long format(repeated instances)

**EDIT**: In response to Stefan's comment I've provided some of the data in a more reproducible format.

```
structure(list(record_id = 1:6, subjectid = c("M001", "M002", 
"M003", "M004", "M005", "M006"), interviewid_1 = c(349976L, 351977L, 
NA, 349979L, 349980L, 349981L), endtime_1 = c("7/8/2021 17:02", 
"8/24/2021 16:48", "", "7/15/2021 16:32", "7/8/2021 16:06", "7/8/2021 15:09"
), cjanx_1 = c(33.83, 53.99, NA, 74.63, 38.85, 70.59), cjanx_cat_1 = c("Normal", 
"Moderate", "", "Severe", "Mild", "Severe"), cjanx_duration_1 = c(79.491, 
68.437, NA, 43.784, 145.51, 57.151), cjdep_1 = c(30.76, 62.59, 
NA, 75.91, 50.36, 62.59), cjdep_cat_1 = c("Normal", "Mild", "", 
"Severe", "Mild", "Mild"), cjdep_duration_1 = c(81.288, 63.692, 
NA, 81.121, 123.557, 61.212), cjss_1 = c(28.06, 50.88, NA, 59.62, 
37.77, 30.34)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like the data to look like this

```
SubjID           Time_1      Anx   Anx_Cat    Dep    Dep_Cat
  M001   12/12/2002 11:30PM   80     Severe    30     Norm
  M001   3/8/2003 11:30PM     40     Mild      20     Norm
  M002   7/10/2002 5:00PM    10    Moderate   48     Mild
  M002   10/10/2002 5:00PM    10      Norm     60     Moderate
  T101   11/11/2006 11:30PM   29      Norm     50     Moderate
```

I have tried using the pivot_longer code.

```
InterviewPivot<-CATMHData %>% pivot_longer(cols = c('Time_1','Time_2'...etc)names_to = 'InterviewNumber', values_to = 'IdNumber')
```

I've tried melt

```
CATLong <- melt(CATMHData, id.vars = c("record_id"),measure.vars = c("anx_1","anx_2",etc.),variable.name= "Anxiety",value.name= "Score")
```

I'm not sure what else I can do. I usually get an error indicating that they can't combine an 'integer' and 'character'. Or it will format into long format but incorrectly. (see below)

```
recor…¹ subje…  time_1…³ cjanx_1 cjanx…⁴  cjdep_1 cjdep…⁶
     <int> <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>   <chr>  
 1       1 D001    12/12/2002…    80 Severe    30   Normal 
 2       1 D001    12/12/2002…    80 Severe    30   Normal
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! As is your issue is hardly reproducible. Could you share your data via `dput()`, i..e type `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET[1:11]))` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post. This will give us the first five rows and eleven columns of your data in a reproducible format.

Comment: Hi, thank you for catching that for me. I've edited based on your suggestions. Hopefully I can get some help in figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

It was not easy to understand your data. I had to format it a bit and have read it in with `read::read_delim` - see below at **DATA**. After cleaning the colnames and extracting whitespaces the main task was then to run some `pivot_longer`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |> janitor::clean_names() |> 
  mutate_if(is.character, ~stringr::str_replace_all(., "\\s", "")) |> 
  mutate(time_1 = stringr::str_replace(time_1, '_', ' '),
         time_1 = lubridate::as_datetime(time_1)) |> 
  mutate_at(vars(c(anx_1, dep_1, anx_20, dep_20)), as.numeric) |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(anx_cat_1, anx_cat_20),
               names_to=NULL, values_to="Anx_cat", values_drop_na = T)  |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(anx_1, anx_20), 
               names_to=NULL, values_to = "Anx", values_drop_na = T) |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(dep_cat_1, dep_cat20),
               names_to=NULL, values_to="Dep_cat", values_drop_na = T)  |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(dep_1, dep_20), 
               names_to=NULL, values_to = "Dep", values_drop_na = T) |> 
  group_by(subj_id) |> 
  slice(1, n()) |> 
  select(-time_20, subj_id, time_1, Anx, Anx_cat, Dep, Dep_cat)


#> Warning in mask$eval_all_mutate(quo): NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#> # Groups:   subj_id [3]
#>   subj_id time_1              Anx_cat    Anx Dep_cat    Dep
#>   <chr>   <dttm>              <chr>    <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 D001    2012-12-20 14:11:30 Severe      80 Norm        30
#> 2 D001    2012-12-20 14:11:30 Mild        40 Norm        20
#> 3 D002    2007-10-20 14:05:00 Moderate    10 Mild        48
#> 4 D002    2007-10-20 14:05:00 Norm        10 Moderate    60
#> 5 T101    2011-11-20 18:11:30 Norm        29 Moderate    50
#> 6 T101    2011-11-20 18:11:30 NA          29 Moderate    50
```

---

**DATA**

```
df <- readr::read_delim("
SubjID|Time_1             |Anx_1|Anx_Cat_1 |Dep_1| Dep_Cat_1|Time_20           |Anx_20 |Anx_Cat_20| Dep_20 |Dep_Cat20
D001  |12/12/2002_11:30PM |80   |Severe    | 30  |Norm      |3/8/2003;11:30PM  |40     |Mild      |    20  |   Norm        
D002  |7/10/2002_5:00PM   |10   |Moderate  | 48  |Mild      |10/10/2002;5:00PM |10     |Norm      |    60  |   Moderate
T101  |11/11/2006_11:30PM |29   |Norm      | 50  |Moderate  |                  |NA     |NA        |    NA  |  Moderate
", delim ="|")
```

Comment: This looks great. How would I adjust the code to account for the multiple instances of each variable? As there are currently up to 50 repeated instances, and it would be a cumbersome and long code if I added each one by name.